# Как организовать взаимодействие микросервисов на django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, микросервисы

Делаю проект с микросервисной архитектурой на django rest framework. Ситуация следующая: есть микросервисы "users" (создание аккаунтов, аутентификация) и "chats" (чаты между пользователями на websocket). Нужно связать модель пользователя с чатами и сообщениями (участники, отправители). Каким образом можно сделать что-то подобное?